# How to get x rows from each category in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix that contains many rows, let's say more than 5000 rows from each category and I would like to get 4500 rows from each category. How to do it in R?

I know that there is unique, but this is getting just one element per category, but I need N elements per category.

---

Here is my data:

```
    cat    f1    f2    f3
1   a      15    20    sdr
2   b      8     6     zrf
3   a      54    6     sf
4   c      32    8     azr
5   b      65    98    arfg
....
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  Is your data actually a `matrix` or a `data.frame`?  If the former, how are your groups defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One 'brute-force' kind of approach would be to split your data by group and then simply take the `head` of `N` rows.  Then simply bind them all together for your new `data.frame`.  This is the essence of 'split-apply-combine'.

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B"), each=10), var=rnorm(20))

# Number of Rows
N <- 5
# the split, apply(i.e. head), combine approach
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, f=df$group), function(x) head(x, n=N)))
```

The same approach will work if you data is in a `matrix` with a column containing some sort of unique group identifier and you call `split.data.frame` directly.  It will still split your matrix in to a list of 'sub' matrices.

```
mat <- matrix(c(rep(c(0,1), each=10), rnorm(20)),20,2)

do.call("rbind", lapply(split.data.frame(mat, f=mat[,1]), function(x) head(x, n=N)))
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by @akrun below, you could also use `dplyr` if your object is a `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    slice(seq(N))
```

Comment: OPs data is in a matrix.

Comment: I have a problem: the category has changed: a became a.NUMBER, so I have now N different categories of each category. :D

Comment: @sop Those are just rownames.  The group itself should not be changed.  Simply set your `row.names(new_data) <- NULL`

Comment: LOL, I have not seen it that it is a rowName ... sorry

Comment: If in case the data is a data.frame. an option with dplyr is `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(group) %>% slice(seq(N))`